# Flash Actionscript3:Session gets deleted on key press in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, session-cookies

I have an application in which when a user logs in a session is created for the user and he can play different games. I have handled arrow keys in my flash swf for selecting different game. But whenever I use keyboard to select a game my session expires. Session does not expire when I select through mouse. I have added my keylistener to the stage.

Comment: which session are talking about?

Comment: user session .Each time when a user logs in I create a cookie which maintains the session

Comment: what server side do you use to generate the cookie? PHP, ASP.NET... Also you have shared no info about the game or the code, how are we supposed to help?

Comment: check if anything like "newSession()" that you obviously have is called when you process keypresses in your listener. This is most likely a code flow design error.

Comment: I use Scala as serverside code to generate cookies .Using a REST call i get all game informations for the user from the server .I render each game as a movie clip on my flash page .When a  user clicks or selects the game using arrow key and press enter the game is played.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Sandeep. You may find you have a better chance of getting an answer if you post some of the code that you've used. Show us what you've done, and what you expect to happen, and what's happening instead. This way it's easier for people to help.